# There is anyway to force google form to be always RTL?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have created this form:

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSepL1NX2ZVNFBDtbvFZqWrHlXVRUznljb6GkJBv2XJ5XCTBpg/viewform

there is  a way to force aligment to RTL no matter what?

Comment: Have you used the language parameter in the link? Checked the Google forms issue tracker?

Comment: As i understand, the parameter link method dosent work anymore. I also tried it with no luck

Comment: fair. Seems like information you should include as a part of your question, since it will prevent anyone else from suggesting you try it, and will show that you have done at least some research before asking.

Comment: I guess you are right. Sorry

Comment: You may check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text-alignment) regarding the text alignments in Google Apps Script. Likewise, this [Enum HorizontalAlignment](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/horizontal-alignment) is used to manipulate the alignment of Paragraph contents.

Comment: @abielita those are for `DocumentApp`. This is a Google Form, i.e. `FormApp`.

Answer (score 5):

You could try and change your preferred language by:

- open the menu in the top-left corner of the "Forms" homepage.
- choose "settings"
- change your default language to your RTL language (Hebrew, I guess).

All of your forms will be RTL now.

Comment: Will your forms then display RTL to all those who open it, even if they don't have the same "Forms" default in their own google account? or is it only a personal setting applying to your own view of forms?

Comment: it's only a personal view. people will see it according to their own settings

Answer (score 2):

This "gold product expert" says "No."

https://support.google.com/docs/thread/6243808?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for a solution to this, I have found a workaround which might not be so elegant, but it is practical.

While it is possible to change the language preference in the Google settings, you can also write an *RTL paragraph manually*.

1. Using a word processor (ie. Microsoft Word), create a document and change it to RTL format (the icon is shown below).
2. Write a line and copy the **whole line** (Select the line not the text inside the line; There must be a little whitespace selected at the end of the line/paragraph for this to work);
3. next, paste it into the Google Forms and it should work.

[image]